# Log files in MAGMA

Tags: magma-ca

At Uni, we are using MAGMA. I'd like to create a log file. That should be done with `SetLogFile('FileName')`. The result of that, however, is `User error: Identifier '20.10.txt' has not been declared or assigned` (`FileName` being `20.10.txt`). Also, `load 'inputfile.magma'` seems not to work. I'm working on Mac OS X 10.7.5. Why do those things happen and how do I solve these problems?

Comment: Has anybody seen this? It's been up for a whole 2 weeks and 3 days now. I need an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's a damn basic mistake, and I apologize, but if someone who is (or should be) supposed to teach you at least a bit of MAGMA doesn't tell you strings are delimited by double quotes `""` and not signle quotes `''` in MAGMA, how exactly are you supposed to guess you should write `SetLogFile("20.10.txt")` after a semester of MATLAB where strings are delimited by `''` and so you would have `'20.10.txt'`? I sort of found out by myself, and then tonight, in the middle of a web search, I realized that of course, double quotes, and wondered *if* he *is* supposed to *teach* us MAGMA or only to show us random examples of MAGMA usage with no other purpose whatsoever. As for the `load` thing, I will check that is the right name and come back with either an edit to this or a follow-up, or nothing at all, since the name was from memory and might have been deformed.

Comment: The file.may be something the teacher had readied on the lab's computer, another thing he _failed_ to tell us students altogether :).